# prolog treats function call as structure definition

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment to define basic arithmetic as incrementations of zero (i.e, `add(inc(inc(inc(zero))),inc(inc(zero)),Z)` gives `Z = inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(zero)))))`).

add is implemented as

`add(zero, Y, Z) :- Z = Y.`
`add(inc(X), Y, Z) :- add(X, Y, V), Z = inc(V).`

and i'm trying to implement mul as

`mul(zero, Y, Z) :- Z = zero.`
`mul(inc(zero), Y, Z) :- Z = Y.`
`mul(inc(X), Y, Z) :- mul(X,Y,V), Z = add(Y,Y,Z).`

but this treats `add(Y,Y,Z)` as a structure definition instead of the predicate add and just returns something like `add(add(inc(inc(zero)), inc(zero)), add(inc(zero),(inc(zero)))`
does anyone know how to make it treat add as a predicate?

Comment: That's because `inc(X)` in this context isn't a function call in Prolog. Similarly, `add(Y,Y,Z)` is just a structure if you unify that term with `X` in `Z = add(Y,Y,Z)`. It is, indeed, just a structure. This is basic Prolog behavior. Prolog doesn't have functions as you know them. It doesn't execute terms/structures as functions. You can call a predicate in certain contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Without looking into the specifics of you code, in general, just *use* it:

```
mul(inc(X), Y, Z) :- mul(X,Y,V), add(Y,Y,Z).
```

If this expresses `(x+1)*y=z` as `x*y+y=z`, it should have been

```
mul(inc(X), Y, Z) :- mul(X,Y,V), add(V,Y,Z).
```

instead. Without backtracking, Prolog is a lot like a single-assignment functional language with code in A-normal form, where all interim values are explicitly named.

The unification `Z = add(Y,Y,Z)` indeed treats both its arguments as Prolog terms. One is a logical variable, the other a compound term.